Force / power needed to operate an accordian frame
Sorry the question is a bit vague, but I don't know how to phrase this "dilemma"
If you've seen a mobile lift, you'll know that they are a series of "X" shapes joined together. By pulling two opposite pivot points together, the "X" shape narrows, and the object gets taller. Now imagine the same mechnaism horizontally. That is the basis of a camera crane. One central pivot becomes a fulcrum, and the front is balanced by a counterweight at the back. Again, as the "X" shapes are elongated - the back also moves the counterweight away from the fulcrum, and it remains balanced.
Here is my questions. Firstly, given "mechanical (dis)advantage" or similar equations, would it require a lot of "work" to take a pair of pivots, and physically push them apart? Given the weight of the metalwork (about 5kg) which extended 4m, thus needing a 20kg counterweight - and friction of pivots etc - would it need a lot of "power" to push the pivots apart ? (The CAME-TV version uses a motor to push the pivots apart, but I've no idea how much Newtons etc would be required)
Now imagine that same rig at a 45 degree angle. There is a 10kg load at the front of the fulcrum, and a 10kg counterbalance. The "X" is extended, pushing the 10kg UPWARDS  whilst the 10kg weight moves DOWNWARDS. Again, is the motor doing a lot of "work" to push those pivot points apart? (To my mind, I see a elevator lift with a load / counterbalance, where the motor does very little actual lifting, and simply controls the speed at which the unit moves)
I am not a scientist / maths wiz / engineer, so please can you give me a guide in Layman's terms, and not go overboard with the Newtons / power / force equations.
I don't want to spen time and money building the unit if it's going to be a non-starter mechanically.
NB: When the unit is in the 45 degree position, the force of gravity would make the counterweight "automatically" want to descend to ground, sending the camera skywards. With the motor controlling the pivot points moving apart, it would "hold" the weight in any position. That makes me think that the motor would have to have gears so it can "lock" in any position.
Again, I'm probably using all the wrong jargon, (such as "locking" a motor, such as a threaded rod isn't able to turn a worm gear on motor shaft, but the worm gear on motor can turn the rod) so please be kind !

I'll be honest, I skimmed this, and when I got to the descriptions, gave up. Draw a diagram!

are you referring to a scissor lift?

Follow the energy. Start going about accounting for energy lost to friction and energy spent lifting stuff. Once you have that, look at your motor and torque on it throughout the movement.
